# Как узнать длину списка без функции len или цикла?

Tags: python

Как с помощью try/assert/except узнать длину списка без функции len, цикла?Возможно так сделать нельзя, но по крайней мере мне в голову ничего путного не приходит.

Comment: рекурсия?......

Comment: Вызов метода `__len__`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Вариант 1**
Получился абсурдный код, но все условия выполняются :)

1. узнать длину списка
2. с помощью try/assert/except
3. без функции len, цикла

```
lst = [[1], 2, '3', {4}]
try:
    assert 1 == 0
except:
    print(sum(map(lambda x: 1, lst)))
```

```
4
```

**Вариант 2**
Еще одна мысль пришла. Если добавить к списку доп. элемент - сам список, то этот элемент будет уникальным и, получив его индекс, мы определим длину списка. Обернуть этот код в `try/assert/except` можно по желанию по аналогии с вариантом 1 :)

```
lst = [[1], 2, '3', {4}]
print((lst+[lst]).index(lst))
```

```
4
```

**Вариант 3**
Мыслительный процесс продолжается :)
Даже все `try/assert/except` при деле

```
try:
    assert lst != []
    print(list(enumerate(lst))[-1][0] + 1)
except AssertionError:
    print(0)  # для пустого списка
```

Comment: Ого, спасибо не догадался бы, про мап мало пока что знаю

Answer (score 2):

Все условия выполнены. Даже `assert` есть, хоть он и не нужен:

```
def length(a):
    assert True

    def search(i):
        try:
            a[i]
        except IndexError:
            return i
        return search(i + 1)

    return search(0)


lst = [[1], 2, '3', {4}]
print(length(lst))
```

> ```
> $ python length.py
> 4
> ```

Answer (score 0):

чисто из спортивного интереса можно изпитониться и задействовать функцию reduce из модуля functools:

```
from functools import reduce

print(reduce(lambda x,y: x+1, lst, 0))
```